# RESTful routes - routes doesn't support all CRUD operations

Tags: rest, server, routes

I want to implement a server storing and manipulating data.

I have a route for adding data, a route for updating the data, a route for showing the data
and a route for deleting the data.

Does it mean the server isn't RESTful since not every route enabling GET,POST,PUT,DELETE ?

Thank you

Comment: REST is more than just simple CRUD. By route I guess you mean own URIs for each of those tasks. This does not sound RESTful at all, IMO, as you don't take caching into account and don't actually have a resource you alter with those operations in mind. REST focuses on resources and on the interaction concepts used for centuries on the Web and attempts to provide such a "Web surfing" experience to applications as well

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean the server isn't RESTful since not every route enabling GET,POST,PUT,DELETE

No.  There's no requirement that every route supports every HTTP method token.  That's why we have [405 Method Not Allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5) and [OPTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7).

If reads, updates, and deletes use different resource identifiers, then you are probably not providing a particularly satisfactory [caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) experience.  [Cache](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4) is an architectural constraint in the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).

So *that's* where I would say you aren't being RESTful.

Part of the point of REST is the uniformity of the interfaces - every REST API should understand messages in precisely the same way that HTTP compliant document store understands them.  When you do that, then all of the technology we've built up over the years for talking to HTTP compliant document stores *just works*.

> Embrace HTTP as an application protocol -- [Jim Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s)